# Make a Solana program pay for the transaction

Tags: blockchain, solana, anchor-solana

I'm not sure that is possible, but what I would like to do is to make the program pay for the transaction cost and make the user use the program for free.

In my mind the process would be:

1. I send some Solana to the account of the program to handle future transactions.
2. A user interact with the function SaveData
3. (Inside this function in the future will be some sort of mechanism to check if the user can interact with the function without paying)
4. The program would pay for the transaction, so the user don't have to pay even a single Lamport.

My code is:

```
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct SaveData<'info> {
    #[account(init, payer = system_program, space = 8 + 50 + 32 )]
    pub data_account: Account<'info, DataState>,

    #[account(mut)]
    pub authority: Signer<'info>,

    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}
```

```
#[account]
pub struct DataState {
    pub authority: Pubkey,
    content: String
}
```

I tried setting `system_program` as the payer, but if I try to build the program with anchor it gives me this error:

```
error[E0599]: no method named `exit` found for struct `SaveData` in the current scope
  --> programs/test-smart-contract/src/lib.rs:5:1
   |
5  | #[program]
   | ^^^^^^^^^^ method not found in `SaveData<'_>`
...
61 | pub struct SaveData<'info> {
   | -------------------------- method `exit` not found for this
```

How can I achieve what I want to do?

---

Update

In order to manage this problem, I started developing this service: [cowsigner.com](https://cowsigner.com)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately every transaction has a fee payer which is specified and needs to sign on the transaction and be a signer account.

System program is a native program on Solana and you're misusing it in your case. This is the official definition for it:

> Create new accounts, allocate account data, assign accounts to owning programs, transfer lamports from System Program owned accounts and pay transaction fees.

If you wish to pay for the fees then you would need a dedicated account, that is specified as the feePayer on each transaction and signs on each transaction as well.

Comment: Hello, thankyou for your reply.

How would you handle a feePayer? I mean, let's suppose that I'm going to create this account to pay all the fees; Do I have to let the private keys of my feePayer on the frontend application?

Comment: feePayer is a field that's specified on the Transaction object from the solana web3 npm package. 

To the other part of the question, I would recommend storing the private key on the backend and have an API that is responsible for signing the transaction. 

Example: 
You would create the transaction, specify the dedicated key to be the feePayer, and sign it on the backend. Then you would serialize it and send it to the client on the front end. Then the FE deserializes it and the user signs and sends the transaction.

Comment: Here's a link to the transaction object https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/classes/Transaction.html#feePayer

Comment: Do you think that for this kind of implementation Anchor is enough, or maybe is better if I start study real solana programming?

Comment: If you wanted to do this, you can transfer SOL from the program's account to the user's account to comp their transaction fee.  They'll need some SOL to initiate, for example, 5000 lamports, but the program could then transfer 5000 lamports back to them.